# Create slice with dynamic struct

Tags: go

I'm trying to create function that receives empty struct and returns slice of that struct type.

For example -

```
type MyStruct struct {
  Id            int
}
type MyOtherStruct struct {
  Name          string
}

getDynamicSlice(MyStruct{}) // will return []MyStruct{}
getDynamicSlice(MyOtherStruct{}) // will return []MyOtherStruct{}
```

What would be the best way to implement such function in Go?

Comment: Don't. Go is a statically-typed language with no generics or dynamic types. What are you actually trying to do that you think you would need this? Creating a slice of a type is already shorter than the function call you showed.

Comment: Give more context on what you are trying to do. What will you do with the slice?  What size and capacity should the slice have?

Comment: I concur with this-^^^^ also. You can do it what you want with the `reflect` package - but unless you are writing some generic framework, stay away from this path. Even Rob Pike - the co-inventor of `go` - recommends to stay away from `reflect` - and he's written more reflect code than anyone would care to.

Comment: He doesn't have to use reflect, he can just return slice of interfaces:
func getDynamicSlice(in interface{}) (out []interface{}) {
 out = make([]interface{},1)
 out[0] = in
 return
}

Comment: `interface{}` is another slippery slope that should be avoided.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make

Comment: For what it's worth, `reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(v))).Elem().Interface()` returns a slice of v's type.  That may or may not be useful given the greater context of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I will give more context.
I'm creating worker that queries db, process the data and send to kafka.
The idea is to make the code generic so it would work with different queries.
I'm using `dbx.Select` that receives struct slice as parameter, I would like this slice to be dynamic depending on which table i'm querying.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a type switch:

```
func getStruct(i interface{}) interface{} {
    switch s := i.(type) {
    case MyStruct:
        // do something here with type MyStruct
        s.ID = 3
        return s
    case MyOtherStruct:
        // ...
        s.Name = "abc"
        return s
    }
    return i

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iTlYP9yYuQw

BUT you should handle this carefully, because Go is strictly with types. You should respect this.

When you call that function you should use then a type assertion, to get the correct type again:

```
s, ok := getStruct(MyStruct{}).(MyStruct)
if !ok {
    // ...
}
fmt.Println(s)
```

#### Some more Information about that pattern

Because a lot of comments under the question are about not using `interface{}` I want to write something more about the use case here. Interfaces in general have no concrete type information. It does not matter if you are using `interface{}` or `io.Reader`. Both interfaces does not allow you to access parameters of the value under the interface. You should always think about this, when you are talking about empty interfaces.

So if your function returns an interface you will allways have this kind of problem. I think almost everybody already made a lot of functions, which are returning an interface. Because `error` is also just an interface. So the whole error handling can use type-switches like this.